# Spring Security access denied error (403) for authenticate user

Tags: jboss, spring-security, jetty, spring-webflow

I have a strange problem with spring security. There's an application (.war file) on the jboss server using spring security and spring web flow. Everything works fine until I run (though maven) a jetty server with an application that simulates other system (it's only a web service). After that I get 403 server error each time I try to enter into particular web flow on the jboss application (this application use spring web flow, the jetty one - not). The error occurs just before redirect to url with flow execution key.

I've investigated that problem with debug logging and it seems that authentication disappears between redirects.

I tried to change a port of the jetty server but it didn't help.
I believe it's connected with threads (where spring security keeps authentication data), but I don't know why that happen if jboss and jetty are running into separated virtual machines.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved that problem, so I'll answer my own question:) Maybe it help somebody...

It's not about threads, it's about cookies. The jetty application add a JSESSIONID cookie on path /. That cookie interferes with the JBoss JSESSIONID cookies so the session is mistaken.

I've changed the path of the Jetty application and everything works fine.